# How can I use several SQL SELECT queries as WHERE clauses in php?

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

```
$sql = "INSERT into x (y,z,t) 
VALUES ((SELECT userID FROM users WHERE username ='".$usersql."'),"
."'"."(SELECT itemID from items WHERE category ='".$category."'),"
."'".$amountdays."')";
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Possibly, `."'".(SELECT itemID from items ...` should be `."(SELECT itemID from items ...`

Comment: However if any of the 2 subqueries returns more than one row, you query will fail.

Comment: Just debug your `$sql` variable and run the result direct on the db to see what is wrong. Actually first create a working query on the db and then make sure your $sql generate the same value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use PDO or mysqli with prepared statements. Then you can define variables for your values and set them after the query. That makes it more readable and you prevent sql injections in your code.

https://www.php.net/manual/de/pdo.prepared-statements.php

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT into x (y,z,t) 
VALUES (
    SELECT userID FROM users WHERE username = :username, 
    SELECT itemID FROM items WHERE category = :category, 
    :amountdays
)";

$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
$stmt->bindParam(':category', $category);
$stmt->bindParam(':amountdays', $amountdays);
```

Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of formatting will go a long way:

```
$sql = "INSERT into x 
  (
    y,
    z,
    t
  ) VALUES (
    (SELECT userID FROM users WHERE username = ?),
    (SELECT itemID from items WHERE category = ?),
    ?
  );
";
```